# How to auto login to jupyterhub in ubuntu machine

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyterhub

I am new to python and jupyterhub, I have installed juputerhub ubuntu machine in the cloud. I want to access the jupyterhub without login from anywhere. can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

I tried below configuration in `jupyterhub_config.py`

```
c.Authenticator.auto_login = True
```

my problem is not resolving from this

please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Jupyterhub is to create a multi-user Hub which spawns, manages, and proxies multiple instances of the single-user Jupyter notebook server.Hence authentication for each user.

For your case if you don't need any authentication (only one user) then simply use Jupyter notebook directly.

OR

you can use Dummy JupyterHub Authenticator made by yuvipanda ([Link](https://github.com/jupyterhub/dummyauthenticator))

### STEPS

#### Install dummy authenticator

```
pip install jupyterhub-dummyauthenticator
```

#### In jupyterhub_config.py

```
c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = 'dummyauthenticator.DummyAuthenticator'
```

P.S.
`c.Authenticator.auto_login` is for Single Sign-On (SSO) not for login from anywhere without any credentials.